# Подойдет ли MacBook для c# разработчика?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mac

Можно ли писать на c#, используя мак? Ну и в целом, если купить макбук, то можно ли работать с платформой .net?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: А как же x-code?

Answer (score 8):

Скажу так: не стоит равняться на макбуки, т.к. это далеко не самые мощные устройства. Их в основном используют либо те, кто работает в веб - стеке (и то не во всём), либо разработчики / дизайнеры под мак / айос. Если интересует ноутбук для разработки под платформу .net, то вам придётся использовать Visual Studio. Учитывая её огромнейшие возможности в написании / отладке / сопровождении / тестировании ПО, программа достаточно тяжёлая, а со всякими решарперами и пр. она начинает потреблять ещё больше ресурсов. Поэтому, по характеристикам можно сказать следующее: минимум 6 - 8 гигабайт ОЗУ, желательно SSD диск, процессор от i5. Если хочется красоты, то можете обратить свой взгляд на линейку Zenbook от Asus, либо аналогичные ультрабуки от HP / Dell. И сугубо моё имхо: нужны большие мониторы, т.к. та же вижуал студия обзавелась достаточно большим кол-вом окошек (окна вывода, интерпретации, локальных / видимых данных и тд), которые должны быть постоянно видны.

Comment: Не стоит отвечать на явный оффтопик. Ну и к тому же - есть же студия под мак, вполне рабочая, с нормальной поддержкой core и xamarin

Comment: @PashaPash, это не студия, а огрызок, т.к. может только в кор и ксамарин (вы это и сами озвучили).